# Is it possible to find out what discord bot a token belongs to?

Tags: discord, access-token

I got multiple discord bots and sometimes it would be useful to find out to what bot a token belongs to via the API or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Javachord and I've found there's a `getYourself()` in `DiscordApi` that returns a `User` which represents the current bot.

I'm not sure how that maps to the Discord API itself though

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution.
Discord has an API endpoint `users/@me` that returns the current user's user object.
Try this for an example:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bot <token>" https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me
```

Discord also sends back a user object (part of lots more info) as part of the Identify process when using its websocket gateways, but this probably isn't what you would want.